Balkan family tree JS: how to show all element of the chart
I have a tree - https://codepen.io/igor-isaev/pen/XWLGVWM
//JavaScript
var options = getOptions();

var chart = new FamilyTree(document.getElementById("tree"), {
    mouseScrool: FamilyTree.none,
    scaleInitial: options.scaleInitial,
    siblingSeparation: 120,
    template: 'john',
    nodeBinding: {
        field_0: "name",
        field_1: "title",
        field_2 : "bday",
        img_0: "img",
    }
});


chart.load([
    ...
]);


function getOptions(){
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var fit = searchParams.get('fit');
    var enableSearch = true;
    var scaleInitial = 1;
    if (fit == 'yes'){
        enableSearch = false;
        scaleInitial = FamilyTree.match.boundary;
    }
    return {enableSearch, scaleInitial};
}

Despite some issues with layout I want to show all tree at once without navigation (tbh it seems to me that the tree begins collapsing much earlier than it could) e.g. here is much better solution - https://code.balkan.app/family-tree-js/royal-family-tree#JS.
I saw this issue Expanding the graph in Balkan FamilyTree Js library which tells me that my wish is impossible but it was much than year ago and may be someone succeeded?
Will be very grateful for any piece of advice - it really seems to me that my settings for the graph are not optimal and reading the official documentation doesn't resolve my problem.

This is Zornitsa from BALKAN App technical support team.
It is still impossible, but now we are working on the new implementation, where you will be able to see all the nodes.

Hi, is it done? can we see the changes or new implementation live demo. We are looking for similar requirement and purchase.

Hi, we have released Family Tree Maker:
https://balkan.app/FamilyTreeMaker
but we are still working on Family Tree JS.

This is great, is there a setting on load, we can expand everything and fit to screen?   Fit to screen, i think can be done with custom options, hope i am not wrong?
scaleInitial = FamilyTree.match.boundary;

Here it looks like expanded and fitted on the screen:
https://code.balkan.app/temp/new-family-tree-js#JS

Great thanks @zorry, where is the documentation for this new family tree? to verify on all other features like view details and customization?

We still don't have any documentation. as it is still not released officially.

When we can expect the release? Because we are planning for subscription
